# Is this sentence correct?(relate to "how")

Tags: grammar

the sentence that I want to understand is below.

"How would solve the homeless problem in San Francisco?."

First, Is this sentence correct?, and I can't find subject in sentence.
I could conceive that "how" is the subject.
As everyone knows, 'how' is adverb.
A native speaker wrote the expression like above though, I doubt whether it is right.
Is there anyone who explains about that in detail?

Comment: It's probably a typo for "how would you solve...?" or "how would one solve...?"

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is wrong. It should say something like, "How would *you* solve the homelessness problem?" In that case, "you" is the subject.

Comment: It's also possible that the missing subject is a "that," referring to a previously-mentioned suggestion. "How to solve...?" is another possibility.

Comment: @randomhead Yes,  "that" would work also.  Pretty much any noun would work. "How would busses solve the homelessness problem?"